# Зачем LinkerPleaseInclude

Tags: c#, .net, ios, swift, xamarin

Делал кастомный `UITextView` и сталкнулся с проблемой при байндинге текстового поля прога просто вылетала

```
set.Bind(_messageField.TextView).For(l => l.Text).To(vm => vm.Message);

string _message;
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _message, value); }
    }
```

`Необработанное исключение: System.ArgumentNullException: отсутствует информация о событии источника в MvxWeakEventSubscription Имя параметра: sourceEventInfo в MvvmCross.Platform.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription 2[TSource,TEventArgs]..ctor(UIKit.NSTextStorage source, System.Reflection.EventInfo sourceEventInfo, System.EventHandler 1 [TEventArgs] targetEventHandler) [0x00017] в <6adc0d5857264558a9d45778a78ae02a>: 0 на MvvmCross.Platform.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription 2[TSource,TEventArgs]..ctor(UIKit.NSTextStorage source, System.String sourceEventName, System.EventHandler 1 [TEventArgs] targetEventHandler) [0x00012] в <6adc0d5857264558a9d45778a78ae02a>: 0 в MvvmCross.Platform.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakSubscriptionExtensionMethods.WeakSubscribe [TSource, TEventArgs] (источник TSource, System.String EventName, System.EventHandler 1[TEventArgs] eventHandler) [0x00000] in <6adc0d5857264558a9d45778a78ae02a>:0 at MvvmCross.Binding.iOS.Target.MvxUITextViewTextTargetBinding.SubscribeToEvents() [0x00053] in <614c9ef828c14ba687a40ec2656f480f>:0 at MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.CreateTargetBinding(System.Object target) [0x00057] in <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0 at MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding..ctor(MvvmCross.Binding.MvxBindingRequest bindingRequest) [0x0002f] in <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0 at MvvmCross.Binding.Binders.MvxFromTextBinder.BindSingle(MvvmCross.Binding.MvxBindingRequest bindingRequest) [0x00000] in <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0 at MvvmCross.Binding.Binders.MvxFromTextBinder+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Bind>b__0 (MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxBindingDescription description) [0x00018] in <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0 at System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectArrayIterator 1[TEventArgs] eventHandler) [0x00000] in <6adc0d5857264558a9d45778a78ae02a>:0 at MvvmCross.Binding.iOS.Target.MvxUITextViewTextTargetBinding.SubscribeToEvents() [0x00053] in <614c9ef828c14ba687a40ec2656f480f>:0 at MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.CreateTargetBinding(System.Object target) [0x00057] in <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0 at MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding..ctor(MvvmCross.Binding.MvxBindingRequest bindingRequest) [0x0002f] in <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0 at MvvmCross.Binding.Binders.MvxFromTextBinder.BindSingle(MvvmCross.Binding.MvxBindingRequest bindingRequest) [0x00000] in <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0 at MvvmCross.Binding.Binders.MvxFromTextBinder+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Bind>b__0 (MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxBindingDescription description) [0x00018] in <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0 at System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectArrayIterator 2 [TSource, TResult].MoveNext() [0x0003a] в <8bc31b0df50a4d32b3f1d5af764165ad>: 0 в MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.AddBindings(MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.IMvxBindingContextOwner view, объект System.Object, System.Collections.Generic. IEnumerable 1[T] bindings, System.Object clearKey) [0x0001d] in <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>:0 at MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.AddBindings(MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.IMvxBindingContextOwner view, System.Object target, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 1 [T] bindingDescriptions, System.Object clearKey) [0x00018] в <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>: 0 в MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.AddBinding(MvvmCross.BindingBindingContext.IMvxBindingContextOwner view, System.Object target, MvvmCross. Binding.Bindings.MvxBindingDescription bindingDescription, System.Object clearKey) [0x0000b] в <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>: 0 в MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBaseFluentBindingDescription'1 [TTarget].Apply() [0x0001f] в <866b1e46764b48aab0d408952a6f006f>: 0 в BALAHA. iOS.Views.RecordingView.SetupBindings() [0x00418] в /Users/BALAHA_mbp/Projects/BALAHA/BALAHA/iOS/Views/RecordingView.cs:799 в BALAHA. iOS.Views.RecordingView.ViewDidLoad() [0x0002f] в /Users/BALAHA_mbp/Projects/BALAHA/BALAHA/iOS/Views/RecordingView.cs:114 at (оболочка, управляемая на основе) UIKit.UIApplication: UIApplicationMain (int, string [], intptr, intptr) в UIKit.UIApplication.Main(System.String [] args, System.IntPtr, делегат System.IntPtr) [0x00005] in/Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/f70a1348/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 в UIKit.UIApplication.Main(System.String [] args, System.String mainClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in/Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/f70a1348/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 в BALAHA.iOS.Application.Main(System.String [] args) [0x00001] in/Users/BALAHA_mbp/Projects/BALAHA/BALAHA/iOS/Main.cs:17 2018-01-12 18: 23: 28.985 BALAHA.iOS [888: 372317] Необработанное управляемое исключение: отсутствует информация о событии источника в MvxWeakEventSubscription`

После этого увидел совет добавить в `LinkerPleaseInclude` собственно для чего это делается и что такое `LinkerPleaseInclude`

```
public void Include(UITextView textView)
    {
        textView.TextStorage.DidProcessEditing += (sender, e) => textView.Text = "";           
    }
```

Comment: Думаю, фраза вырвана из контекста. Дайте ссылку, где вы это увидели.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235351/uitextview-throws-exception-when-binding-to-viewmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Xamarin Linker используется в проектах iOS и Android для удаления неиспользуемого кода из скомпилированных сборок. Это помогает сократить конечный размер apk или ipa. Однако, он часто действует слишком неразборчиво и также удаляет те методы и поля, которые нужны. Так часто случается, если на методы ссылаются только путем отражения.

Вот [тут](https://xamdev.ru/linking-in-xamarin/) можно почитать подробнее на русском, а [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=macos) на английском.